# Is it possible to repeat getopt

Tags: c, getopt

I'm trying to create a basic shell with builtin commands, and I'm having some issues with getopt. Here is the output (using valgrind):

```
$ mkdir -p foo/bar
mkdir
-p
foo/bar
FLAGON
$ mkdir -p foo/test
mkdir
-p
foo/test
==15377== Invalid read of size 1
==15377==    at 0x5201BBE: _getopt_internal_r (in /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so)
==15377==    by 0x5202CEA: _getopt_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so)
==15377==    by 0x5202D37: getopt (in /usr/lib/libc-2.17.so)
==15377==    by 0x40351A: shell_ns_cmd_mkdir (shell.c:542)
==15377==    by 0x403AB4: normal_shell_cb (shell.c:610)
==15377==    by 0x402E8E: shell_mainloop (shell.c:402)
==15377==    by 0x401B67: main (main.c:52)
==15377==  Address 0x54e0912 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 3 free'd
==15377==    at 0x4C2AD3C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15377==    by 0x402C93: shell_mainloop (shell.c:384)
==15377==    by 0x401B67: main (main.c:52)
==15377== 
$
```

And here is the source (clipped):

```
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    puts(argv[i]);
}
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "p")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'p':
            puts("FLAGON");
            mkparents = true;
            break;
        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid option -- %c", optopt);
            ret = 127;
            goto end;
            break;
    }
}
```

So the first time it runs it (`mkdir -p`) recognizes it (`-p`) and the second time it runs, it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that your stdout buffer isn't getting flusehd the second time for some reason? Try fflush(stdout) after puts?

Comment: "the first time it [the program] runs it [the program, or maybe `getopt()`?] recognizes **it**". What is *it*?

Comment: @Code-Guru, sorry, **it** as in the flag (`-p`)

Comment: @MiJyn What do you mean by "the second time *it* runs". Do you mean that your run your program twice or do you mean the second time the `while` loop iterates? (Feel free to edit your question with these clarifications.)

Comment: @Code-Guru, right, it's the second time the `mkdir` command (the one that I posted my source for) runs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to scan multiple vectors you need to reset `getopt` by setting `optind` to 1.

> The variable optind is the index of the next element of the argv[]
>   vector to be processed. **It shall be initialized to 1 by the system**,
>   and getopt() shall update it when it finishes with each element of
>   argv[].

If setting `optind` to 1 doesn't work, also try `0`, I think I remember reading about that somewhere.

Comment: Setting `optind` to 1 fixed it, but I still had warnings from valgrind, so I tried setting it to 0, and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Note that POSIX [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) says: _The variable `optind` is the index of the next element of the `argv[]` vector to be processed. It shall be initialized to 1 by the system, and `getopt()` shall update it when it finishes with each element of `argv[]`. If the application sets `optind` to zero before calling `getopt()`, the behavior is unspecified. When an element of `argv[]` contains multiple option characters, it is unspecified how `getopt()` determines which options have already been processed._   […continued…]

Comment: If you read to the end of the argument list (so `getopt()` returns `-1`), then resetting `optind = 1;` should reset it for reparsing. However, if you have, for sake of argument, and option string of `"abc"` and a command line argument `-abc` and you try to reset the parsing after reading only `a` or `b`, you may not have achieved a reset — the parsing could continue with `c`. Setting to `0` is explicitly unspecified by POSIX; it may or may not be useful — you have to read your implementation's manual, or experiment and hope the result remain valid across upgrades (and worry about porting).

Comment: Here is what man page of getopt says for when to do initialize optind to 0: 

NOTES
       A program that scans multiple argument vectors, or rescans the same vector more than once, and wants to make use of GNU extensions such as '+'  and  '-'  at the  start  of optstring, or changes the value of POSIXLY_CORRECT between scans, must initialize getopt() by resetting optind to 0, rather than the traditional value of 1.  (Resetting to 0 forces the invocation of an internal initialization routine that rechecks POSIXLY_CORRECT and checks for GNU  extensions